# HttpClient crashes on DefaultHttpClient creation

Tags: java, web-services, httpclient

Ive been trying(failing) to use the [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) library to send http requests to a webservice and ive just made a simply class to test out a get request...

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://localhost/mywebservice/1");
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            String line = "";
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My problem is it doesnt get past the 1st line, it throws the following runtime exception...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.<init>(AbstractHttpClient.java:5)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.<init>(DefaultHttpClient.java:7)
    at Main.main(Main.java:20)
```

And I cant find any solutions online anywhere because everything seems to either say its a problem of using it with the android sdk and not having the emulator running but im not using the package bundled with the android sdk. Or its to do with running unit tests but this is just a simple main method in a class.

Any help would be great because ive been struggling with this all day

Thanks

Comment: This is probably a stupid question, but do you also have the Http *Core* library?  (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/index.html)  I know the HttpClient has some dependencies here.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, and the link from lenbloy helped (thanks!). Here is what to do (in eclipse):

1. Right-click your project.
2. Build Path -> Configure Build Path...
3. Go to the "Order and Export" tab.
4. Select "httpclient-4.1.3.jar" (or any other version you might use)
5. Click the "Top" button on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this Question that describes what "Stub!" means.

[Apache DefaultHttpClient invocation results in “java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382499/apache-defaulthttpclient-invocation-results-in-java-lang-runtimeexception-stub)

In summary:

This is Android's way of telling you that you cannot run that unit test on that platform. Unit tests that involve interacting with the Android platform (e.g. the network in this case) need to be run on an actual Android device or a functioning Android emulator.

Apparently, you are running the unit tests against the stub classes in the Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Weird. Doesn't [this](http://jeffangelini.com/unit-testing/java-lang-runtimeexception-stub/) help?

Other suggestion: to be sure you are not using the android lib, run the code with the VM `-verbose` option, (`java -verbose Myclass` ; or add the switch to the 'VM arguments' in the Eclipse run-configuration tab)  and see from which jar is the AbstractHttpClient loading.

Comment: I had looked at that but... "Eventually, though, I found this post that informed me that the JUnit library needs to be at the top of the test project’s build order." Im not using JUnit or any other external jars apart from the ones included in the apache http client download.

Comment: It seems an Android implementation is getting ony your way somehow. Look at my added suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

After version 28, include this in your Manifest file:

`HttpClient` legacy library has been deprecated.