# How to run android code in REPL

Tags: android, read-eval-print-loop

I have an android application with a lot of communication. I'd like to run code for android inside REPL , for development, debug etc

like this

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
print(client.execute(new HttpGet("some url"), new BasicResponseHandler()));
```

by this way I can see my changes very fast, without running on phone or emulator.

I've tried to add android.jar to beanshell, but it does not work that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You won't be able to run classes that are part of the Android platform (e.g. `HttpClient`) in a REPL, because the methods in android.jar are all stubs.  The real implementation of these methods resides on your phone or emulator, so you'll have to run the emulator at a minimum.

See [Apache DefaultHttpClient invocation results in "java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382499/apache-defaulthttpclient-invocation-results-in-java-lang-runtimeexception-stub) for more details.

For example, if you run the code you posted in a REPL, you'll get a RuntimeException similar to the following:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.<init>(AbstractHttpClient.java:5)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.<init>(DefaultHttpClient.java:7)
    at CodeSnippet_10.run(CodeSnippet_10.java:7)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.snippeteditor.ScrapbookMain1.eval(ScrapbookMain1.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.snippeteditor.ScrapbookMain.evalLoop(ScrapbookMain.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.snippeteditor.ScrapbookMain.main(ScrapbookMain.java:35)
```

---

If you want to verify this firsthand, create a new Java project in Eclipse, then create a new scrapbook page in your project (`File > New > Other... > Java Run/Debug > Scrapbook Page`).  Add android.jar to the project's build path, then right-click the scrapbook page, select `Set Imports` and import the `org.apache.http.*` package.  When you execute the snippet (Ctrl + U), you will get an exception similar to the one I posted above.